# issue with php session destroy

Tags: php, session

I am facing an issue with PHP session. PHP session is destroyed if I leave the page before it fully loads.

I have two link pages like so: page_1 and page_2. Both pages are visible after login. If I click on the page_1 link then click page_2 and back to page_1 before page_2 fully loads, the session is destroyed. However, if I click on the page_1 link after page_2 fully loads, it keeps the session. It is little mysterious to me. Can anybody help me?

Comment: looks like a browser caching item to me

Answer (score 0):

Try add these `header()` functions in page_1 to tell the browser to not cache the page.

```
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

Anyway, the Back browser button is posible to display the page without refreshing data/ 
content.

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause of the issue. Ckeditor created a loop of requests. It tries to send request several times to a php file with does not exist. Some content (text, images, smiley images ) of page_2 was posted via Ckeditor . When I opened the page, those content (I think smiley images) tries to send requests and make delay to load the pages. I deleted those content, now the session issue is fixed.